# HTML Button onclick link not working

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl

I am using the following button in my JSP page but it is giving me error and refusing to open the page in href, can someone please tell me what I am missing here?

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="location.href='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/inventory/edit-product/?productid='${productinfo.id};">Edit Product</button>
```

thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misplaced one apostrophe. It should be

```
 <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="location.href='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/inventory/edit-product/?productid=${productinfo.id}';">Edit Product</button>
```

Comment: Didn't work as it didn't parse the ${productinfo.id}

Comment: So is the problem with invalid product id or javascript error on button click?

Comment: the product id is there for sure, can see it even in HTML code but the JS don't add it to the url

Comment: Please post that HTML fragment with a button. This should work.